# convexity and the interior sphere condition

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, convex-analysis

Consider $\Omega $ a open, convex bounded subset of $R^n$.
Let $x_0 \in  \partial \Omega$. I believe that exists a open ball $B \subset \Omega$ such that $\partial B \cap \partial \Omega = \{ x_0 \}$. (this is the interior sphere condition in $x_0$) ?  I have no idea how to proof ...

Someone can help me to prove or give a counter example for the question ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You have to ask some regularity on the boundary, in order that this result is true. For example, if $\partial\Omega\in C^1$, then this result is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy counter example. $\Omega = int([0,1]^n)$ and $x_0 = (1,\ldots,1)$ then there is no ball which we want.

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $\Omega$ be the standard open unit square. Let $x_0 = (1,1).$ There is no open disc contained in the open square for which $x_0$ is a boundary point.

Answer (score 0):

Any triangle is convex bu never satisfies the interior sphere condition at the vertices.